# Urn problem - Why isn't P(Yellow M&M is from 1994 bag) = P(Bag from 1996|Green M&M)*P(Bag from 1994|Yellow M&M)?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

> The blue M&M was introduced in 1995.  Before then, the color mix in a bag of plain M&Ms was (30% Brown, 20% Yellow, 20% Red, 10% Green,
> 10% Orange, 10% Tan).  Afterward it was (24% Blue , 20% Green, 16%
> Orange, 14% Yellow, 13% Red, 13% Brown).
>
> A friend of mine has two bags of M&Ms, and he tells me that one is from 1994 and one from 1996.  He won't tell me which is which, but he
> gives me one M&M from each bag.  One is yellow and one is green.  What
> is the probability that the yellow M&M came from the 1994 bag?

I found this on [Allen Downey's blog](http://allendowney.blogspot.com/2011/10/all-your-bayes-are-belong-to-us.html) and read the author's solution. I understand that `P(Yellow M&M came from 1994 bag)` isn't equal to `P(Bag from 1994|Yellow M&M)` = 0.588 because we have additional information that a green M&M was selected from the other bag.

However, if the probability of selecting a M&M from either bag is independent (and we know the M&Ms didn't come from the same bag), why can't we calculate `P(Bag from 1996|Green M&M)*P(Bag from 1994|Yellow M&M)` = 0.666*0.588? This gives us 0.392, which is not the correct answer. The author's solution is provided below for reference.

> Hypotheses:
>
> - A: Bag #1 from 1994 and Bag #2 from 1996
> - B: Bag #2 from 1994 and Bag #1 from 1996
>
> Again, P(A) = P(B) = 1/2.
>
> The evidence is: E: yellow from Bag #1, green from Bag #2
>
> We get the likelihoods by multiplying the probabilities for the two
> M&M:
>
> P(E|A) = (0.2)(0.2) P(E|B) = (0.1)(0.14)
>
> For example, P(E|B) is the probability of a yellow M&M in 1996 (0.14)
> times the probability of a green M&M in 1994 (0.1).
>
> Plugging the likelihoods and the priors into Bayes's theorem, we get
> P(A|E) = 40 / 54 ~ 0.74
>
> By introducing the terms Bag #1 and Bag #2, rather than "the bag the
> yellow M&M came from" and "the bag the green came from," I avoided the
> part of this problem that can be tricky: keeping the hypotheses and
> the evidence straight.

Comment: I agree with your approach and analysis.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes. My question is why the following approach is incorrect: P(Yellow M&M is from 1994 bag) = P(Bag from 1996|Green M&M)*P(Bag from 1994|Yellow M&M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if the probability of selecting a M&M from either bag is independent ...

Boop.   The probabilities for selecting those M&M from the bags is *not* independent.   They are *conditionally* independent for a given arrangement of the two bags.

> why can't we calculate P(Bag from 1996|Green M&M)*P(Bag from 1994|Yellow M&M) = 0.666*0.588?

Your expectation that a bag is from 1994 *will* be influenced *both* by knowing that you drew a yellow M&M from it *and* by knowing that you drew a green M&M from the other bag.

Plus, *for any given evidence*, the event that *this* bag is from 1994 will not be independent of the event that *that* bag is from 1996.   They are actually the same event after all.

---

You have the events $Y, G, A, B$ for selecting yellow from the first bag, green from the second, the first bag is from 1994, the second bag is from 1994.   $A, B$ are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, and $Y,G$ are conditionally independent for each event $A,B$, so by using the definition for conditional probability, and the Law of Total Probability:

$$\begin{split}\mathsf P(A\mid Y,G) & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(Y,G\mid A)\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(Y,G)} \\ &= \dfrac{\mathsf P(Y\mid A)\mathsf P(G\mid A)\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(Y\mid A)\mathsf P(G\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(Y\mid B)\mathsf P(G\mid B)\mathsf P(B)}\\ &= \dfrac{\mathsf P(Y\mid A)\mathsf P(G\mid A)}{\mathsf P(Y\mid A)\mathsf P(G\mid A)+\mathsf P(Y\mid B)\mathsf P(G\mid B)} &\because \mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(B) \\ \text{Similarly}\\ \mathsf P(A\mid Y) & =  \dfrac{\mathsf P(Y\mid A)}{\mathsf P(Y\mid A)+\mathsf P(Y\mid B)}\\\mathsf P(A\mid G) & =  \dfrac{\mathsf P(G\mid A)}{\mathsf P(G\mid A)+\mathsf P(G\mid B)} \end{split}$$

Comment: Thanks for bringing up conditional independence. The author should have used the term. I looked at this problem in his book (Think Bayes) and was confused when he wrote, "For example, if A is true, the yellow M&M came from the 1994 bag with probability 20%, and the green came from the 1996 bag with probability 20%. Because the selections are independent, we get the conjoint probability by multiplying." Here, by conjoint probability I assume he means likelihood.

Comment: @jenkat, No, it is the the *conditional joint probability* for the events. $$\mathsf P(Y,G\mid A) = \mathsf P(Y\mid A)~\mathsf P(G\mid A)$$